# Why won't my While Loop work?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I am doing the video tutorials from The New Boston and I'm on video 20.  Everything has been fine until now but I can't get this one to run.  I've checked against the code in the tut and I just can't see what I'm missing.  I'm sure it's right in front of my face.

Sorry this is so basic, but I'm a total newbie.

This is the video tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPFW_0blw9w

This is my code:

```
var x = 1;

while(x<10){
   document.write(x + "how do you like </br>");
   x++;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where did you put that piece of code? Can you show us the surrounding HTML?

Comment: What does it do? Or not do? You didn't describe the failure other than to say you "can't get this one to run". And as @JosephSilber indicates, a little context is helpful.

Comment: Sorry don't mind, but is your code enclosed in a `script` tag? because other than that there is nothing wrong with that code

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is correct, as verified by running the JavaScript code (exactly as you wrote it) inside Codecademy Labs. If your while loop isn't working, I suspect it has to do with your environment or the state of the document being written, but it is not the code itself. As a fellow newbie, I try running code in two IDE's (codecademy labs being one) to test a lot of code and confirm against this sort of issue, though codecademy can't do file operations.

In addition, if you're interested in knowing why a `for` loop is superior to `while` for this situation, continue reading.

A `for` loop is a loop that comes in handy when you have a fixed index; When you know how many iterations you need, or know how to find out and can work that into the code.

A `while` loop is better at handling situations when an unknown (and unpredictable) number of iterations is required, as it will loop through until the conditions are eventually met.

Keep in mind that what makes it strong also makes it weak; `for` loops are harder to create infinite loops for. Because of the arguments in a `for` loop (IE: `for (index,index<=value,value++)`), most `for` loops self-terminate neatly, or at least it's hard to forget to put the "closing" condition in. `while` loops, however, don't innately ask for a closing statement and thus you *must* explicitly state them inside the loop.

I hope this answers your question, and more.

EDIT: Oh yeah, and `</br>` doesn't work inside the quotes. You can remove it, and it should still do a new line without it; But leaving `</br>` inside the code just has it literally print `</br>` in the line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code the way you wrote it, so there must be an error in some of the code that surrounds this. Alternatively, for the same outcome as this, I would suggest using a `for` loop as such:

```
for (var x = 1; x < 10; x++){
    document.write(x + "how do you like </br>");
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: To be fair, he didn't say what *wasn't* working about his code, only that it wasn't working, so I suggested a workaround. A workaround is most definitely an answer.

Comment: There is no reason this "workaround" would work if the original code didn't.

Comment: A workaround *might have been* an answer if they were trying to solve a problem. Since the OP is clearly learning, and following a tutorial, the goal is to teach them what they did wrong, not give them an alternative. And your "workaround" wouldn't work any better than the `while` loop.